# how to handle alerts in selenium with phantomjs headless browser

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

Selenium version : 3.4.0
phantomjs version : 2.1.1
java : 1.8.0_151

I have tried below things but it didnt work for me.

enter code here

1:

```
webDriver instanceof PhantomJSDriver){
              JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
              je.executeScript("window.alert = function(){};");
              je.executeScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;};");    
              System.out.println("Alert has been handled"); }
            else {
                  Alert a1 = driver.switchTo().alert();
                  a1.accept();  
              }
```

2:

```
      /*((PhantomJSDriver)driver).executeScript("window.alert = function(){}");
      ((PhantomJSDriver)driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");*/
```

3:

```
      PhantomJSDriver phantom = (PhantomJSDriver) driver;
            phantom.executeScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;};");
```

4:

```
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.alert = function(msg){};");
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg){return true;};");
```

5 :

```
PhantomJSDriver phantom = (PhantomJSDriver)driver;
       phantom.executePhantomJS("var page = this;" +
               "page.onAlert = function(msg) {" +
                      "console.log('ALERT: ' + msg);" +
               "};");

       phantom.executePhantomJS("var page = this;" +
               "page.onConfirm = function(msg) {" +
                      "console.log('CONFIRM: ' + msg);"+ "return true;" +"};");
```

Can you please suggest apart from above.

Comment: @akhaouri Hi, a little info. PhantomJS is no longer supported since Selenium version 3.8.0. You can switch to google headless :)

Comment: Thanks @RafałLaskowski for sharing the info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle alert in **PhantomJS** you have to wait for the *alert to be present* and then cast the *WebDriver* to *JavascriptExecutor*. You can use  can use the following code block :

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.alert = function(msg){};");
//or
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg){return true;};");
driver.findElement(By.id("element_which_trigers_the_alert")).click();
```

Comment: If I am using driver.switchTo().alert().accept()--->itd giving same error Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException

Comment: Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: Implemented your updated code but still giving error :Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Invalid Command Method :(

Comment: Implemented the updated code, but its not clicking on "OK" button on the alert.

Comment: we cannot inspect the element of an alert.Any other thing which i can try?

Comment: That is not **element of an alert**. That is the element on which you click **to create the alert**.

Comment: Getting error : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id ''OK''

Comment: it worked with selenium version 3.4.0 ,phantomjs 2.1.1 but it is not working with selenium version 3.0.0 , phantomjs 2.1.1....Can you please suggest.

Comment: it worked with selenium 3.0.0 Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Upvote this/any Answer which is/was useful to you for the future readers.

Comment: yes the code is updated.I have used the same code and have added the xpath/id of the element which triggered the alert